# Do we say "the bolt is coming out" or "the bolt has loosened"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

> [loos‧en](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/loosen) /ˈluːsən/ ●○○ verb     1 [intransitive, transitive] to make
>   something less tight or less firmly fastened, or to become less tight
>   or less firmly fastened OPP tighten
>
> You’ll need a spanner to loosen that bolt.
>
> The screws have loosened.
>
> Harry loosened his tie.

---

And It seems that only 1 dictionary mentions this, other dictionaries don't have this meaning:

> **[come out (of something)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/come-out?q=come%20out)**
>
> ​(of an object) to be removed from a place where it is fixed
>
> This nail won't come out.

---

Look at the picture

[image]

Do we say "**the bolt is coming out**" or "**the bolt has loosened**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these are possible:

> The bolt is *coming out*.

This suggests motion: maybe you are currently turning it with a wrench or your hands and you're saying it's moving, or maybe you're pointing out that over time it is working itself loose on its own.

> The bolt is *sticking* out.

This addresses the current condition of the bolt rather than suggesting motion. You are indicating that the bolt is not completely inserted.

> The bolt is *loose*.

This also addresses the current condition of the bolt, but rather than talking about the degree of insertion, you are talking about the degree of tightness: saying it's "loose" suggests you can turn it with your hands, or easily with a wrench.

The last two aren't necessarily equivalent: a bolt can be fully inserted but still loose; and a bolt can be tight even when not fully inserted (for example, if it has jammed in the threads).

> The bolt has loosened.

This is at best non-idiomatic, if not wrong. "Loosen" is most often used as a transitive verb: a person loosens a thing, for example. The bolt itself hasn't caused anything else to loosen. One could say instead "the bolt *has been loosened*" or "the bolt *has become loose*." This would mean that at some point the bolt has changed from being tight to being loose.

Comment: but the example in the dictionary is "The screws have loosened." because "loosen" is both transitive and intransitive verbs.